# which ppa or repo has libgmime-2.0-2a?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, packaging, libraries

where can I download this package?  I've found it in [hardy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/libgmime-2.0-2), but it seems to be unavailable.

I'm trying to install dbmail from http://debian.nfgd.net/debian :

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo aptitude install dbmail -v
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbmail{b} 
The following packages are SUGGESTED but will NOT be installed:
  dbmail-mysql dbmail-pgsql 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 315 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,053 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  dbmail: Depends: libgmime-2.0-2a which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     dbmail [Not Installed]                             



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Current status: 0 broken [+0], 5 updates [+0], 27 new [+0].
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ aptitude search libgmime
i   libgmime-2.4-2                        - MIME message parser and creator library - runtim
i   libgmime-2.4-dev                      - MIME message parser and creator library - develo
p   libgmime-2.4-doc                      - MIME message parser and creator library - docume
i   libgmime2.4-cil                       - CLI binding for the GMime library               
p   libgmime2.4-cil-dev                   - CLI binding for the GMime library               
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ tail /etc/apt/sources.list

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric multiverse restricted universe main



deb http://debian.nfgd.net/debian unstable main
thufir@dur:~$
```

I upgraded to 12.04

Answer (score 2):

You likely won't find a PPA with such an old version of libgmime for a new release (the current version appears to be 2.6 (libgmime-2.6-0)). Possible solutions include:

1. Contact the upstream developer of the software and see if a newer version would work instead.
2. Compile the libgmime version you need from source.
3. Install the Natty version of libgmime-2.0-2a

Comment: it's a dependency for dbmail.  There's no repo?

Comment: Looks like dbmail was dropped in Oneiric, probably because it doesn't support a newer version of libgmime (I didn't look too much into this). I've updated my answer with another possibility.

Comment: can you perhaps explain how to install something from natty?  I upgraded to 12.04

Comment: You would have to manually download the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgmime&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all and install it with dpkg

Comment: I'm tired, admittedly, but when I look at the packages I don't see libgmime-2.0.2a devel for i386..?  I think I'm on a fools errand perhaps, where the thing I want to install seems to have amd64 requirements.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/libgmime-2.0-2a/download and  http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/libgmime-2.0-2-dev/download would be my guess